# Advance Nesting Tables Using Index by, is Record and Nested Tables

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

Can you tell me why this is not working? I would like to add a value on the Nested table a,b,c

PL/SQL

```
TYPE chars is table of varchar2(30);
TYPE numbers is table of number;
TYPE t_content IS RECORD(a  numbers, b chars, c  chars);
TYPE t_table IS table of t_content index by varchar2(30);
v_information t_table;
```

THEN INSIDE THE DECLARE

```
v_information ('Index1').a:= numbers();
```

I can't access to the tables inside a,b,c using a table with index values. what is wrong?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? What is the remaining of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a record variable first.

Try:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE chars is table of varchar2(30) ;
  TYPE numbers is table of number ;
  TYPE t_content IS RECORD(a  numbers, b chars, c  chars) ;
  TYPE t_table IS table of t_content index by varchar2(30) ;
  v_information t_table;
  my_record t_content;
BEGIN
  my_record.a := numbers( 1,2,3,4 );
  my_record.b := chars('a','b','c');
  my_record.c := chars('x','y','z');
  v_information('Index1') := my_record;

  my_record.a := numbers( 22,44 );
  my_record.b := chars('aa','bb','cc');
  my_record.c := chars('x','y');
  v_information('Index2') := my_record;
END;
/
```

Demo: